# shiny getting the data from a service

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I did a shiny app using de database in format csv and updating the database once a month and it works really well, but now I want to take it to the next level, so, I want that the shiny take the data from the service in which it is stored,because I want have the data in real time. I have some questions.

1. Is that possible?
2. If that is possible, could some one please gave me some information (Examples will be great)
   Currently the information is stored in format json, and when I need the information, the systems engineer downloads it and sends it to me

Comment: Do you have some API access? You can "send" a GET request to get the data using `httr` or `httr2`. You can also just read the data with `jsonlite`? (not sure if it accepts links to datasets).

Comment: Could you please show me some example about GET?

Comment: Sorry, it would be a bit hard to give an example right now (late where I am). If you have a link to some repo, I can PR there or you can put some sample code and the website in the question then I (or someone else) can start with that.